# WordPress tiny mce editor not adding <br> in visual editor

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, line-breaks

I am facing some weird problem in WordPress default editor. I installed WordPress 3.4.2 and after few CSS customizations, I started to create pages.

While creating pages I came to know that visual editor is not adding any line breaks `<br>`. Instead of that it's adding `<div> </div>` tags.

Any suggestions to solve this problem?

Comment: check if brs are recognized as avalif elements. you may use the html button and enter brs manualy - if you click the html-button after you updated your code and the brs are gone it is probably not in the valid_elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I tested in wordpress 3.4.1   it replaced with `<P>` instead . whatever .  i guess you should  just need to spaced in `<div>` tag like the following

```
.something div { margin:20px 0px }
```

in CSS